# Using Outlook Redemption, How do I get a list of Shared Calendars?

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

We're using:

Redemption 6.3
Windows 11
Office 365
Outlook Version 2307 Build 16626.2022

What I would like to do is retrieve the list of calendars listed under the **Shared Calendars** group.

This code only returned a couple of publicly shared folders that aren't in the "Shared Folders" group pictured below.

```
    RDOFolder calendar = rdoSession.GetSharedDefaultFolder("--mailbox name--", rdoDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    foreach( RDOFolder folder in calendar.Folders )
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(folder.Name);
    }
```

USING "OutlookSpy" I can find what I'm looking for in the NavigationPane, but this is likely not how I'll need to get to the information I want using Redemption.

[image]

HERE IS WHAT I WAS ABLE TO DO WITH INTEROP.  IT WORKS, BUT NOT SURE IF IT WOULD HAVE BEEN EASIER WITH REDMEPTION

```
    private static IEnumerable<string> ListSharedCalendars()
    {

        Outlook.Folder myCalendar = null;
        Outlook.Explorers myExplorers = null;
        Outlook.Explorer myCalendarExplorer = null;
        Outlook.CalendarModule calendarModule = null;
        Outlook.NavigationGroups navGroups = null;
        Outlook.NavigationFolders myNavigationFolders = null;
        Outlook.NavigationPane myNavigationPane = null;
        Outlook.NavigationModules myNavigationModules = null;

        List<string> calendarList = new List<string>();
        

        try
        {
            application = new Outlook.Application();
            nameSpace = application.GetNamespace("MAPI");

            myCalendar = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar) as Outlook.Folder;

            myExplorers = application.Explorers;
            myCalendarExplorer = myExplorers.Add(myCalendar, Outlook.OlFolderDisplayMode.olFolderDisplayNormal);



            if (myExplorers.Count > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    myNavigationPane = myCalendarExplorer.NavigationPane;
                    myNavigationModules = myNavigationPane.Modules;

                    calendarModule = myNavigationModules["Calendar"] as Outlook.CalendarModule;
                    navGroups = calendarModule.NavigationGroups;

                    int groupCount = navGroups.Count;

                    try
                    {
                        for (int x = 1; x <= groupCount; x++)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                calendarList.Add(navGroups[x].Name);
                                myNavigationFolders = navGroups[x].NavigationFolders;

                                int navfolderCount = myNavigationFolders.Count;
                                for (int y = 1; y <= navfolderCount; y++)
                                {
                                    calendarList.Add("\t-" + myNavigationFolders[y].DisplayName);
                                }
                            }
                            catch (System.Exception ex)
                            {
                                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                if (myNavigationFolders != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myNavigationFolders); myNavigationFolders = null; }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (navGroups != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(navGroups); navGroups = null; }
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception otlEx)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(otlEx);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (navGroups != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(navGroups); navGroups = null; }
                    if (calendarModule != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(calendarModule); calendarModule = null; }
                    if (myNavigationModules != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myNavigationModules); myNavigationModules = null; }
                    if (myNavigationPane != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myNavigationPane); myNavigationPane = null; }


                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myExplorers != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myExplorers); myExplorers = null; }
            if (myCalendarExplorer != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myCalendarExplorer); myCalendarExplorer = null; }
            if (calendarModule != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(calendarModule); calendarModule = null; }
            if (navGroups != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(navGroups); navGroups = null; }
            if (myNavigationFolders != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myNavigationFolders); myNavigationFolders = null; }
            if (myNavigationPane != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myNavigationPane); myNavigationPane = null; }
            if (myNavigationModules != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myNavigationModules); myNavigationModules = null; }
            if (myCalendar != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(myCalendar); myCalendar = null; }


            nameSpace.Logoff();
            

            if (nameSpace != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(nameSpace); nameSpace = null; }
            if (application != null) { Marshal.ReleaseComObject(application); application = null; }
        }

        return calendarList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS far as I know, it is stored in the Outlook favorites, accessible though `RDOSession.Favorites`. The type (`RDOFavorite.FolderType`) is `fftCalendar` (2).

Comment: Interesting.  Never thought to look in Favorites.  Learn something new every day.   I'll begin exploring and get back to you.

Comment: I forgot about it either :-) Had to watch the the store notifications In OutlookSpy to figure out that `"IPM.Microsoft.WunderBar.Link"` message gets created. And that is what `RDOSession.Favorite`s exposes.

Comment: I've updated the image in my post.   You'll see that I can access the folder if I start at the Explorer Window and go through the NavigationPane.   I'm not entirely sure how to traverse the RDO objects in order to get this information.  Listing all the calendars in "Favorites" gets me only so far.  I get all the calendars, but I don't see information on the Calendar Group to which they belong.

Comment: Wasn't sure if this could be done strictly with Redemption.  I've updated my post.  It contains what I found using OutlookSpy and my implementation using Interop.

Comment: That information is saved in the PR_WLINK_GROUP_NAME property on the MAPI level, but Redemption does not currently expose it. Are you looking to just read the group name, such as "My Calendars"?

Comment: Yes,  I would like to read the group names, as well as the members of the group.   So, yes; "My Calendars" then the calendars contained in that group.

Comment: Contact me offline at redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com for an update version with that property exposed

Comment: Email sent to support address.

Comment: The updated version adds `RDOFavorite.GroupName` / `GroupHeaderID` / `GroupClsid` / `StorageItem` properties.

Comment: Update is working perfectly.   Will mark as answer.